# How to optimize non-linear equations in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

[image: System of non-linear equations]

I have written until here but I couldn't continue. How can I define x0,x1 and x2? How can I solve this problem?

```
def nonlin(a,b,c):
    return [3*x0-cos(x1*x2)+ a, x0*x0-81*(x1+0.1)**2+ sin(x2)+b, exp(-x0*x1)+20*x2+c]
```

Comment: you may want to take a look [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.nonlin.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try solving this using [`scipy.optimize.fsolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html):

```py
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from numpy import cos, sin, exp

# Define the non-linear equations
def equations(X, a,b,c):
    x0, x1, x2 = X
    return [3*x0-cos(x1*x2)+ a, x0*x0-81*(x1+0.1)**2+ sin(x2)+b, exp(-x0*x1)+20*x2+c]

a = 1.0
b = 0.5
c = 2.5

# Using (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) as an initial vector
x0, x1, x2 = fsolve(equations, x0=(0.,0.,0.), args=(a,b,c)) 
print(x0, x1, x2)
```

**Output**:

```
-6.826133854836766e-06 -0.03657006638562982 -0.17499998751839313
```

Comment: Why did you do this? ---> x0, x1, x2 = X
And why did you assume that a b and c are 1?